# Django multi table inheritance: Find and change parent model

Tags: python, django, inheritance

Suppose I have the following model structure in django:

```
class A(models.Model):  
    x = models.IntegerField()

    def copy(self):
        obj = self
        obj.pk = None
        obj.save()

        return obj

class B(A):
    y = models.IntegerField()

    def copy(self):
        # this method is what I am confused about
        new_parent = super(B, self).copy()  # not sure about this
        obj = self
        obj.pk = None
        # how to set obj's parent model to 'new_parent'
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

I am not sure on how I can access the parent model's object, and how can I make this copy method work?

I have searched quite a bit and couldn't find any answer. Should I just use a one-to-one relation instead?

Comment: i think you need to use foriegn-key relation for the parent model object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a normal parent-child models you will get attribute in child to access parent. You can update this attribute with new parent object.

Also, the way you create parent object may not work, you need to call method on that object.

So I will update child's `copy()` method as:

```
class B(A):

    def copy(self):
        # this method is what I am confused about
        new_parent = self.a.copy()  # change 'a' with appropriate attribute name
        obj = self
        obj.pk = None
        # set obj's parent model to 'new_parent'
        obj.a = new_parent
        obj.save()
        return obj
```

Comment: That was simple! Thanks

Comment: Is there any django doc explaining this in more detail? There is 'a_ptr' and 'a_ptr_id' fields too. What are they for?